# Flask Login and Flask Socket-IO working together

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-socketio

i have been following the Miguel Grinberg Tutorial of **flask** and i make my site work with flask-login. 
Now im adding **flask socket-io** to my site but i encounter a problem. Miguel uses the route '*/logout*' to log out a user, **flask socket-io** documentation talks about sessions and the problem of cookies using flask socket-io, but using miguel route doesnt give me that problem. I think im confussing the term 'session' but also in his video tutorial about flask socket-io he talks about the problem of logging out of a cookie session from a socket without a server side session but... with the 'logout' route that doesnt happen. Also isn't it possible to make a cross site request forgery if i use a route like '/logout' ?

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? I read your description and I don't understand it. Flask, Flask-Login and Flask-SocketIO work well together, if you have a specific problem please describe it in detail.

Comment: hello, thanks for answering, sorry i dont explained well the problem but i dont have it very clear either. In a video talking about flask socket io you said that the last option using only flask login with socket io isnt usable in practically any case because the session changes made in socket io doesnt go back to the regular session of flask login. What are session changes ? that is my main question, what type of things would i like to save for example from a socket io session to a client side one.

Comment: I don't know. In that video I just explain a limitation, if you avoid it then you'll be fine. It seems you are worrying about a problem you don't have then?

Comment: i think i am yes, thanks for answering and also thanks for all the hard work you make answering noobs like me and maintaining the community active and all the commits you make to the flask community.